# Python 3.x - Creating Vertical Lists with symbols representing integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to python and wondered if someone could help me solve this problem I am facing. 
I am able to print a list that displays the information horizontally, however when I try to create a vertical list I cannot seem to implement it or find any other help that can guide me through a similar scenario.

```
    cat1 = 4
    cat2 = 3
    cat3 = 5
    cat4 = 3
    print(" 0 to 29:   ", end=" ")
    for i in range(cat1):
        print("*", end=" ")
    else:
        print("\n 30 to 39:  ", end=" ")
        for i in range(cat2):
            print("*", end=" ")
        else:
            print("\n 40 to 69:  ", end=" ")
            for i in range(cat3):
                print("*", end=" ")
            else:
                print("\n 70 to 100: ", end=" ")
                for i in range(cat4):
                    print("*", end=" ")
     break

This outputs: 
0 to 29:   * * * *
30 to 39:  * * *
40 to 69:  * * * * *
70 to 100: * * *

What I am trying to do is:
| 0 to 29 | 30 to 39 | 40 to 69 | 70 to 100 |
     *          *          *         *
     *          *          *         *
     *          *          *         *
     *                     *         
                           *
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code snippet will produce your desired output:

```
cats = [cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4]
print('| 0 to 29 | 30 to 39 | 40 to 69 | 70 to 100 |')

for i in range(max(cats)):
    c1, c2, c3, c4 = ['*' if i < cat else ' ' for cat in cats]
    print('    {}          {}          {}          {}'.format(c1, c2, c3, c4))
```

You can adapt the amount of spaces between the `{}` indent the asterisks in a different way if you want to

**EDIT:** As @Bram Vanroy pointed out, my for loop can be improved to use `print('' + ''.join(['*' if i < cat else ' ' for cat in cats]))` instead of my two lines, reducing the code to

```
cats = [cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4]
print('| 0 to 29 | 30 to 39 | 40 to 69 | 70 to 100 |')

for i in range(max(cats)):
    print('    ' + '          '.join(['*' if i < cat else ' ' for cat in cats]))
```

Comment: Probably needs to be `if i < cat`?

Comment: You can optimise by using `print('      ' + '          '.join(['*' if i < cat else ' ' for cat in cats]))` instead of the variable unpacking and the string formatting. Note: Stack Overflow seems to trim the number of spaces that I write as a comment. First four spaces, and ten spaces in the join.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, it will work for python 3.6 and higher

```
cat_dict = {'0 to 29': 4, '30 to 39': 3, '40 to 69': 5, '70 to 100': 3}

print(' | '.join(cat_dict.keys()))
for i in range(max(cat_dict.values()) + 1):
    for v in cat_dict.values():
        print(f'   {"*" if i < v else " "}       ', end = '')
    print('\n')
```

for python 2.7 you can use the below

```
cat_dict = {'0 to 29': 4, '30 to 39': 3, '40 to 69': 5, '70 to 100': 3}

print(' | '.join(cat_dict.keys()))
for i in range(max(cat_dict.values()) + 1):
    for v in cat_dict.values():
        print('   {0}       '.format("*" if i < v else " "), end = '')
    print('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it with formatting

```
cats_stats = {
    "cat1": 4,
    "cat2": 3,
    "cat3": 5,
    "cat4": 3
}


print("|   0 to 29   |   30 to 39   |   40 to 69   |   70 to 100   |")

max_cats = max(cats_stats.values())

for row in range(max_cats):
    line = ""
    for cats in cats_stats.values():
        if cats <= row:
            line += "               "
        else:
            line += "       *       "
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
|   0 to 29   |   30 to 39   |   40 to 69   |   70 to 100   |
       *              *              *              *       
       *              *              *              *       
       *              *              *              *       
       *                             *                      
                                     *
```